# How to remove a string part of a column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataset in Python.
I've loaded it into a dataframe so that I can perform a linear regression on it.
But first I need to clean the dataframe so that it only has number values.
One of the columns has movies' runtime in it, phrased like this:

```
**Runtime**
142 min
175 min
152 min
202 min
96 min
...
```

And so on.
How do I remove the 'min' part of the column so that the column only shows the number part?
i.e.,

```
**Runtime**
142
175
152
202
96
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need numeric before `min` use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Runtime'] = df['Runtime'].str.extract('(\d+)\s*min', expand=False).astype(int)
```

Or convert values to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and convert to minutes from seconds by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and divide 60:

```
df['Runtime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Runtime']).dt.total_seconds().div(60).astype(int)
print (df)
   Runtime
0      142
1      175
2      152
3      202
4       96
```